# How to show a timestamp on a checkbox selection using angular?

Tags: html, angularjs

I was trying to figure out how to show the timestamp when we check the checkbox and it should disappear when we uncheck. Could some one please help me how to do that in angular? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do following

HTML

```
<input
    type="checkbox"
    name="mycheckbox"
    value="{{time}}"
    ng-model="isChecked"
  > {{time}}
```

Angularjs Controller

```
$scope.isChecked=false;


  $scope.$watch('isChecked', function() {
        if($scope.isChecked){
           $scope.time=Date.now().getTime();
        }else{
           delete $scope.time;
        }
    });
```